# Deterministic scalar function to get day of week for a date

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

SQL Server, trying to get day of week via a deterministic UDF.

Im sure this must be possible, but cant figure it out.

UPDATE: SAMPLE CODE..

```
CREATE VIEW V_Stuff WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
SELECT    
MD.ID, 
MD.[DateTime]
...
        dbo.FN_DayNumeric_DateTime(MD.DateTime) AS [Day], 
        dbo.FN_TimeNumeric_DateTime(MD.DateTime) AS [Time], 
...
FROM       {SOMEWHERE}
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX V_Stuff_Index ON V_Stuff (ID, [DateTime])
GO
```

Comment: Please show some of your code, and how you intend to use this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, i figured it..

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_DayNumeric_DateTime] 
(@DT DateTime)
RETURNS INT WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result int 
DECLARE  @FIRST_DATE        DATETIME
SELECT @FIRST_DATE = convert(DATETIME,-53690+((7+5)%7),112)
SET  @Result = datediff(dd,dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,@FIRST_DATE,@DT)/7)*7,@FIRST_DATE), @DT)
RETURN (@Result)
END
GO
```

Comment: I just posted you should make your implementation :) +1 for you

Comment: No @brad it isn't... see the higher rated answer above.

Answer (score 6):

Slightly similar approach to aforementioned solution, but just a one-liner that could be used inside a function or inline for computed column.

Assumptions:

1. You don't have dates before
   1899-12-31 (which is a Sunday)
2. You want to imitate @@datefirst = 7
3. @dt is smalldatetime, datetime,
   date, or datetime2 data type

If you'd rather it be different, change the date '18991231' to a date with the weekday that you'd like to equal 1.  The convert() function is key to making the whole thing  work - cast does NOT do the trick:

> ((datediff(day, convert(datetime,
>   '18991231', 112), @dt) % 7)
>   + 1)

Comment: if you stick to the 1899-12-31 date you can even skip the convert

`((datediff(day, -1, @dt) % 7) + 1)`

Comment: This works beautifully in a function. Until you try to alter a table and set the computed column, then you get "cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.". This is because the datediff converts the string to a datetime object - and this conversion kills the deterministic ability to use this in a persistent column... unfortunate.

Use this instead (replace the "at" with @,..) : SET (at)datediff = (DATEDIFF(dd, -1, convert(datetime, (at)dbdate, 112)) % 7)+1;

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is way-super-old, but I was trying to do a similar thing and came up with a different solution and figured I'd post for posterity. Plus I did some searching around and did not find much content on this question.

In my case, I was trying to use a computed column PERSISTED, which requires the calculation to be deterministic. The calculation I used is:

```
datediff(dd,'2010-01-03',[DateColumn]) % 7 + 1
```

The idea is to figure out a known Sunday that you know will occur before any possible date in your table (in this case, Jan 3 2010), then calculate the modulo 7 + 1 of the number of days since that Sunday.

The problem is that including a literal date in the function call is enough to mark it as non-deterministic. You can work around that by using the integer 0 to represent the epoch, which for SQL Server is Jan 1st, 1900, a Sunday.

```
datediff(dd,0,[DateColumn]) % 7 + 1
```

The +1 just makes the result work the same as datepart(dw,[datecolumn]) when datefirst is set to 7 (default for US), which sets Sunday to 1, Monday to 2, etc

I can also use this in conjunction with case [thatComputedColumn] when 1 then 'Sunday' when 2 then 'Monday' ... etc. Wordier, but deterministic, which was a requirement in my environs.

Comment: this was an interesting idea, but doesn't work. in my tests, i had to make your `0` a `4`. i'm guessing this has to do with the first day of this year, which was on a Wednesday. i'm not sure how this worked in 2013 when you wrote it because that year started on a Tuesday. @scottE's answer accounts for this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5109557/444382

Comment: according to the definition of deterministic (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx) this solution is deterministic. The reason you probably got a different result was your database setting firstdate (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx). You cannot make a calculated column persisted if it is not deterministic, and this calculation can be persisted

Comment: you state in your solution that you're assuming `@@datefirst` of 7 which is the same as me, so i'm not sure what's causing this to not work for me.

Comment: I think the confusion was that liver had mixed up @@datefirst being 7 and 1. I've updated the answer with a little more clarification and an explanation how it works. I also changed it slightly as I think using the epoch for this is a bit too magical. You can just pick any date from the past that falls on your desired @datefirst and that will occur before all possible dates that you will use.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, by the way. It's pretty understandable and doesn't rely on magic numbers.

Comment: After further experimentation, I've realized that you need to use the epoch for it to be non-deterministic.

Comment: On my MSSQL instance, with `@@datefirst = 7`, I had to use `((datediff(dd, 0, datecolumn) + 1) % 7) + 1` to get the same result as `datepart(weekday, datecolumn)`.

Comment: Ed Avis, that's because the answer incorrectly states that Jan 1, 1990 was a Sunday.  It was a Monday.  Just do a `SELECT DATEPART(dw,'1/1/1900')` and see for yourself.  I hope people reading this answer aren't using the "official" answer, and instead use your corrected formula.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Deterministic scalar function to get week of year for a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432719/deterministic-scalar-function-to-get-week-of-year-for-a-date/11433441)

```
;
with 
Dates(DateValue) as 
(
    select cast('2000-01-01' as date)
    union all 
    select dateadd(day, 1, DateValue) from Dates where DateValue < '2050-01-01'
)
select 
    year(DateValue) * 10000 + month(DateValue) * 100 + day(DateValue) as DateKey, DateValue,        
    datediff(day, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, DateValue), 0), DateValue) + 2 as DayOfWeek,
    datediff(week, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DateValue), 0), DateValue) + 1 as WeekOfMonth,
    datediff(week, dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, DateValue), 0), DateValue) + 1 as WeekOfYear
    from Dates option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an already built-in function in sql to do it:

```
SELECT DATEPART(weekday, '2009-11-11')
```

**EDIT**:
If you really need deterministic UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DayOfWeek(@myDate DATETIME ) 
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
RETURN DATEPART(weekday, @myDate)
END
GO
SELECT dbo.DayOfWeek('2009-11-11')
```

*EDIT again*: this is actually wrong, as `DATEPART(weekday)` is not deterministic.

**UPDATE**: 
`DATEPART(weekday)` is non-deterministic because it relies on `DATEFIRST` ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258863%28SQL.80%29.aspx)).
You can change it with `SET DATEFIRST` but you can't call it inside a stored function.

I think the next step is to [make your own implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_the_day_of_the_week), using your preferred DATEFIRST inside it (and not considering it at all, using for example *Monday* as first day).

Comment: DatePart is non-deterministic, so this is not possible

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution has one problem - it returns 0 for Saturdays.  Assuming that we're looking for something compatible with `DATEPART(WEEKDAY)` this is an issue.

Nothing a simple `CASE` statement won't fix, though.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function, and have @dbdate varchar(8) as your input variable.

Have it return the following:

```
RETURN (DATEDIFF(dd, -1, convert(datetime, @dbdate, 112)) % 7)+1;
```

The value 112 is the sql style YYYYMMDD.

This is deterministic because the datediff does not receive a string input, if it were to receive a string it would no longer work because it internally converts it to a datetime object. Which is not deterministic.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you are looking for, but if this is part of a website, try this php function from http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
function weekday($fyear, $fmonth, $fday) //0 is monday
{
  return (((mktime ( 0, 0, 0, $fmonth, $fday, $fyear) - mktime ( 0, 0, 0, 7, 17,   2006))/(60*60*24))+700000) % 7;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but im looking for an SQL Server scalar function

Answer (score -2):

The day of the week? Why don't you just use DATEPART?

```
DATEPART(weekday, YEAR_DATE)
```

Comment: DatePart is non-deterministic, so this is not possible

Answer (score -2):

Can't you just select it with something like:

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Question is to get the DayOfWeek not the name.