# SQL Server UDF for getting week of year, with first day of week argument

Tags: sql, sql-server, datepart

I'm looking for a SQL Server UDF that will be equivalent to `DATEPART(WEEK, @date)`, but will allow the caller to specify the first day of the week. Somewhat similar to MySql's `WEEK` function. E.g.:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Week (@date date, @firstdayofweek int)
RETURNS int
BEGIN
  -- return result would be the same as:
  --   SET DATEFIRST @firstdayofweek
  --   DATEPART(WEEK, @date)
END
```

My application does not have the opportunity to call `SET DATEFIRST`.

Examples:

```
SELECT Week('2013-08-28', 2) -- returns 35
SELECT Week('2013-08-28', 3) -- returns 36
```

The above results would always be the same, regardless of SQL Server's value for `@@DATEFIRST`.

Comment: So if I submit 2013-08-28 and 2, what should I get back?

Comment: 35. If you submit 2013-08-28 and 3, you should get back 36.

Comment: How about 2013-01-01 and 1?  Also, does 1 represent Sunday or Monday?

Comment: 1. You can check your result against the script: SET DATEFIRST 1;  SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, '2013-01-01');

Comment: 1 represents Monday. Sunday is 7. DATEFIRST doc: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx

Comment: Can you give a couple examples and explain why they return what they do?  I am unclear to what `@firstdayofweek` does for the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a couple of articles that helped me answer to derive an answer to this question:

1. [Deterministic scalar function to get week of year for a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432719/deterministic-scalar-function-to-get-week-of-year-for-a-date/11433441)
2. http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/datetime-calculations-part-3

It may be possible to simplify this UDF, but it gives me exactly what I was looking for:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Week (@date DATETIME, @dateFirst INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  DECLARE @normalizedWeekOfYear INT = DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @date), 0), @date) + 1
  DECLARE @jan1DayOfWeek INT = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @date), 0) + @@DATEFIRST- 7) - 1
  DECLARE @dateDayOfWeek INT = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, @@DATEFIRST- 7, @date)) - 1

  RETURN @normalizedWeekOfYear + 
    CASE
      WHEN @jan1DayOfWeek < @dateFirst AND @dateDayOfWeek >= @dateFirst THEN 1
      WHEN @jan1DayOfWeek >= @dateFirst AND @dateDayOfWeek < @dateFirst THEN -1
      ELSE 0
    END
END
GO
```

Then, executing the following statements would return 35 and 36 respectively:

```
SELECT dbo.Week('2013-08-28', 2)
SELECT dbo.Week('2013-08-28', 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, 8 - @firstdayofweek, @date))
```

Instead of moving the first day of the week you are moving the actual date.  Using this formula the first day of the week would be set using the same number values for days that MS SQL Server uses.  (Sunday = 1, Saturday = 7)

Comment: Shifting the day will not work because you could cross a week boundary . For instance, DATEPART(WEEK, '2013-08-31') returns 35 (@@DATEFIRST = 7) and DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, 8 - 1, '2013-08'31')) returns 36.

Comment: I'm sorry your example above isn't clear.  If the first day of the week is day 7 then DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, 8-7, '2013-08-31')) will return 36 because you just said the first day of the week is Saturday and August 31 of 2013 is the 36th Saturday of 2013.  So it works correctly.  Perhaps you are trying to solve a different problem?

Comment: Some additional clarity, the datepart WEEK is not affected by the DATEFIRST setting in MS SQL Server.  I can't find any specific documentation but I have tested it.  The week is the same regardless of what the first day of the week is.  Also, I had said 8-31-2013 was the 36th Saturday when I should have said it marks the beginning of the 36th week and is actually the 35th Saturday.

Comment: My examples above are correct. DATEPART does rely on DATEFIRST. "When datepart is week (wk, ww) or weekday (dw), the return value depends on the value that is set by using SET DATEFIRST." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
No matter how @@DATEFIRST is
return result as
weekdayName,weekdayNumber
Mo  1
Tu  2
Wn  3
Th  4
Fr  5
Sa  6
Su  7
*/

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnFixWeekday
(
    @currentDate date
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- get DATEFIRST setting
    DECLARE @ds int = @@DATEFIRST 
    -- get week day number under current DATEFIRST setting
    DECLARE @dow int = DATEPART(dw,@currentDate) 

    RETURN 1+(((@dow+@ds) % 7)+5) % 7

END
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. The requirement is that the function must take the first day of week as one of the arguments.