# Select weekend or weekday data from a table based on date param

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2012, case

How can I select data from a table based on weekday or weekend, like
if date is a weekday then select only historical weekday data from the table &
if date is a weekend then select only historical weekend data.

I have tried to do that in this way but no luck

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATE = '08/17/2013'

SELECT datename(dw,@MyDate)

SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE 
datename(dw,DateColumnInTable) IN ( 
CASE WHEN (datename(dw,@MyDate) IN ('Saturday','Sunday')) THEN '''Saturday'',''Sunday'''
ELSE  'Monday'',''Tuesday'',''Wednesday'',''Thursday'',''Friday'
END )
```

Any I can see lots of data in my table for saturday and sunday but this query is giving me blank record set.

Comment: Why down vote? I tried first then I did google about it, after that I search SO and my question is not subjective. Where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATE = '08/17/2013'

IF (DATEPART(weekday, @MyDate) IN (1,7))
    SELECT * 
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE DATEPART(weekday, DateColumnInTable) IN (1,7)
ELSE
    SELECT * 
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE DATEPART(weekday, DateColumnInTable) BETWEEN 2 AND 6
```

If you would like to do it in one clause you can do something like the following, but it may perform worse:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (DATEPART(weekday, @MyDate) IN (1,7) AND DATEPART(weekday, DateColumnInTable) IN (1,7))
OR (DATEPART(weekday, @MyDate) BETWEEN 2 AND 6 AND DATEPART(weekday, DateColumnInTable) BETWEEN 2 AND 6)
```

Comment: DATEPART(weekday,...) isn't deterministic

Comment: @BogdanSahlean No it's not, but you can either use a dates table and join on that, or refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803561/deterministic-scalar-function-to-get-day-of-week-for-a-date

Comment: @Ic My Select clause is quite big so can I do it in one clause ?

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite Edited to include one option

Comment: @Ic. Thanks a lot :) but I still don't know why I got a down vote. Nevertheless, thanks for pushing it though

Comment: I'm not sure about the downvote (it wasn't me) but glad this helped